# Eclipse Windows App - Getting Started

Tags: java, eclipse

I have to questions in this post.  The first one - I can't seem to figure out how build a windows GUI application in Eclipse IDE with Java. I successfully used Eclipse to make a Java Android app after downloading the Android SDK into Eclipse.  I want to generate the same app, but now this time for Windows.

It seems there is no GUI tool in Eclipse for Windows?  Do I need to download additional add-ins for Windows GUI?  I thought the GUI tool/widgets used for Android would be the same but this doesn't appear to be the case.  I see references to Swing, SWT, WindowBuilder... can someone help me sort out which software needs to be loaded into Eclipse to support Windows GUI development?

The 2nd question is how can I take my Java/xml Android App (developed in Eclipse) and compile that code to run on Windows?  I assume I will need to create a comparable GUI in the Windows editor (see first question), and then copy the java code into it?

Thanks!

Comment: In reverse order, you **can't** *use Java/xml Android App (developed in Eclipse) and compile that code to run on Windows* and you might use Swing (100% Java) or SWT (eclipse developed cross-platform Java library built on native code).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you come from a .NET environment. :P

You don't have an easy drag and drop, so to make the Java GUI you'd use SWING: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/

Furthermore, if you have created your android application according to the MVC pattern, you can easily reuse all the logic and just hook up a new controller + view. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller

That's one of the powerfull features of the MVC pattern, makes your model logic really portable.

Anyway, I hope that helps you along :)

Comment: Great Thx! btw - good call... yes, I originally did the app using .net.  Didn't realize it required the .net runtime engine so decided to switch to java (more prevalent, at least on our office machines).  I'll explore swing.  I had assumed Eclipse had a windows gui developer in their standard tool kit.